Are there any short and entertaining English animation channels similar to GAG Anime that can help improve my listening skills?
I've been learning Japanese by watching anime and YouTube videos (I think this is my learning style), especially from these channels:
https://www.youtube.com/@parako
https://www.youtube.com/@marymarymary80s
These videos have great gag humor, which makes them really enjoyable for me. Now, I'm wondering if there are similar English channels with short and funny videos (less than 7 minutes) that have interesting or hilarious storylines.
I've tried watching English-dubbed anime, but it wasn't quite my style. I also looked for English channels with a similar vibe, but they didn't seem as entertaining (or I just couldn't find my type).
If anyone here knows of any English channels with a similar gag anime style, I'd really appreciate it if you'd share them with me!

FYI: Here's what I've got.
For Japanese learners:
https://www.youtube.com/@parako
https://www.youtube.com/@marymarymary80s
https://www.youtube.com/@manimani-people
https://www.youtube.com/@neko-oka
https://www.youtube.com/@jumpchannel
I've found following channels for English:
https://www.youtube.com/@ExplosmEntertainment
https://www.youtube.com/@HowItShouldHaveEnded
https://www.youtube.com/@jaidenanimations
https://www.youtube.com/@LowBudgetStories
https://www.youtube.com/@Domics
https://www.youtube.com/@ImprovementPill
Btw, it doesn't have to be YT channel :))
It's just example...
